# ogr2ogr merge two GeoJSON to one GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, merge

Is ogr2ogr capable of merging two GeoJSON files to a new one?
It is possible to merge shapefiles to one GeoJSON using the VRT driver. But when trying to do the same using GeoJSON files ogr2ogr fails.

VRT is:

`<OGRVRTDataSource>
<OGRVRTUnionLayer name="union">
<OGRVRTLayer name="Bundeslaender">
<SrcDataSource>C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\OGR_Contextmenue\Bundeslaender.geojson</SrcDataSource>
</OGRVRTLayer>
<OGRVRTLayer name="standorte">
<SrcDataSource>C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\OGR_Contextmenue\standorte.geojson</SrcDataSource>
</OGRVRTLayer>
<GeometryType>wkbGeometryCollection</GeometryType>
</OGRVRTUnionLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>`

And the ogr command:

```
ogr2ogr.exe -f "GeoJSON" "C:\Users\root\Desktop\Plugin_new\Shapefiles_Karte\Bundeslaender\Bundeslaender.geojson" "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\OGR_Contextmenue\vrt.vrt" -overwrite
```

The error ogr2ogr gives me is:

`ERROR 1: Failed to find layer 'Bundeslaender' on datasource 'C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\OGR_Contextmenue\Bundeslaender.geojson'.
ERROR 1: Failed to find layer 'standorte' on datasource 'C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\OGR_Contextmenue\standorte.geojson'.`

To clear out: the files are existing at the path given in the vrt. I double checked it. Also the path where the merged GeoJSON file should be created exists and is accessible.
Doing the same with Shapefiles is no problem!
So what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you noticed that for the GDAL geojson driver the layer name is always OGRGeoJSON?

Comment: I don't know what you want to say with that?

Answer (score 5):

You can "merge" GeoJSON with ogr2ogr by appending the second to the first or writing both into one new file if you want to keep the original files.
In your example: use bundeslaender.geojson and standorte.geojson as parameters.
This works for me:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON bundeslaenderUndStandorte.geojson bundeslander.geojson
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -append bundeslaenderUndStandorte.geojson standorte.geojson
```

Maybe it even works with VTR if you use -append instead of -overwrite

Comment: I had geopackage output, but geojson input, so I am not certain if it is exactly the same, but without specifying the layer name (`-nln`) it appends an entire additional layer to the file, instead of appending the rows of the second input layer to the rows of the first input layer.

Comment: What about appending everything to geojson as output and then in the end converting everything to gepackage?

Comment: hmm, either might work, but at the end it is nice to have clean reference to the final layer name for my uses, so I would need to use -nln eventually. Working with a mix of geopackage/sqlite (cold storage), geojson/json (interchange), shapefile (old), geodatabase (from analysts), and postgis/postgresql (production). It would be amazing if everything could be in one format.

Comment: For a.json and b.json with copying `a` to new.json, then trying to append `b`, yields: `ERROR 1: Layer 'b' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.` I can append `a` to `new` over and over. When the FeatureCollection does not have a name, it uses the filename. If I manually add a matching name inside b.json, then it can be appended. Warnings are given if Feature `id` values overlap, but it will append them anyway.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/447359/191643.

Answer (score 2):

You can also merge GeoJSON files using a JSON processing command line tool such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
jq '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [.[] | .features[]]}' --slurp input*.geojson > output.geojson
```

`--slurp` reads all input files into one big array. You get a virtual JSON document with an array as top level element where each input file becomes one element. You can see the effect with `jq . --slurp input*.geojson`.

`.[] |` iterates over the top level array coming from `--slurp`.

`.features[]` iterates over all features in all files. And with `"features": […]` they are output at this place in the output file.

ogr2ogr uses the properties of the *first* input file to determine which properties exist in the output file.

If you happen to have input files with variable properties, you might find that the output is missing some of them, if the first file doesn’t happen to contain all of them.